# Member of struct wont stock in a variable

Tags: c, struct, output

I have a trouble with my code today,
the problem look like this one :

```
void my_function(r_struct *suit) 
{
     sfVector2f position;

     position = get_position(suit->other_vector);
     printf("Output : %f\n", position.x);
}
```

***(get_position return a sfVector2f)***
When i'm doing this way, the output of position is : 0.
But when I did :

```
void my_function(r_struct *suit)
{
     printf("Output: %f\n", get_position(suit->other_vector).x);
}
```

And now output is : 50. I don't understand what am I doing wrong

**Edit:**

```
sfVector2f *get_position(sfVector2f *point_to)
{
     sfVector2f new_pos;
     new_pos.x = point_to.x;
     new_pos.y = point_to.y;
     return (new_pos);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code for the `get_position()` function.

Comment: No offense, but that's quite hard to believe. Good case for a self-contained full, compilable example.

Comment: Btw, typedef-ing a `struct` with a name like `r_struct` is really pointless for many reasons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the return type of `get_position(suit->other_vector)`?

Comment: I added the method of get_position, I don't write it cause I use a custom library named CSFML. I rewrite it cause I know it was write like this. I don't think I have a bad use of the structure, maybe I do.

Comment: I don’t see how the shown function compiles. You return a structure from a function that is supposed to return a pointer. Returning a pointer to a local variable would be undefined behaviour.  Returning a structure is clean and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a pointer to a local variable, when you exit the function that variable will be destroyed and the value it hold will be lost.
If you return an `sfVector2f` it should work as expected and the value it hold b.

```
sfVector2f get_position(sfVector2f *point_to)
{
     sfVector2f new_pos;
     new_pos.x = point_to.x;
     new_pos.y = point_to.y;
     return (new_pos);
}
```